# Can't enable Windows file compression on removable drive?

Tags: windows-7, usb, windows-explorer, compression

I have a USB drive formatted with NTFS. I would like to use "compress contents to save disk space" option, although it is greyed out.

[image]

It works fine on the C: drive. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem was the ntfs allocation unit size on the drive was set higher then 4k.  Reformatted with default allocation size allowed me to use compression.