# Is it possible to enable NTFS compression without formatting?

Tags: ntfs, compression

NTFS offers the option to compress files on the fly, but as far as I know you need to enable this functionality when you format the volume.

Is there a way to enable it on an already formatted NTFS volume, apart for the obvious "move files away, re-format, re-import files". Possibly using a Linux boot?

If not, some insights on the technical why?

**NOTE:** In my case, the checkbox in the properties window for folders (see Techie007 answer) is greyed out, I just guess that it's because it has not been enabled at format time. There is no such checkbox on the drive's properties window

Context: I use win7, I'm using a 3GB external drive, formatted as NTFS with default options

Comment: "you need to enable this functionality when you format the volume." - This is not correct.

Comment: So how do you enable it?

Comment: It is disabled due to the cluster size.

Comment: [Understanding NTFS Compression](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2008/05/20/understanding-ntfs-compression/_).  "Native NTFS compression does not function on volumes where the cluster size is greater than 4KB, but sparse file compression can still be used."  My research was this bing search [here](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%22Compress+this+drive+to+save+disk+space%22+grayed+out&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Can't enable Windows file compression on removable drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/115207/use-windows-file-compression-on-removable-drive)

Change your NTFS allocation unit size to default. It's probably set higher than 4k.

Note: This will require a format because the allocation unit size is set at during the format.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Explorer.
- Right-click a drive, and select Properties.
- Checkmark "Compress this drive to save disk space"
- Hit Apply.
- Wait for compression to complete (may take quite a while if you're compressing an entire drive).

[image]

Comment: That box is absent in my case. Any idea?

Comment: Ahh it's an external drive, that's makes a difference, see the duplicate.